# Deployment package for AWS Lambda with C files

Tags: python, c, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda

I need some libraries in python that uses C files in AWS Lambda. For example I want to use [python-snappy](https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy) library. How can I compile it to be able to use it with Lambda?

EDIT: it seems like Amazon EMR didn't like to install libraries with pip but when I tried to install them on my laptop that runs Linux I was able to install them without problem. Used virtualenv to set up everything and included files from site-packages into my lambda project and it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile it using an EC2 machine with an Amazon Linux image. Compile and include the result in the zip file that you will upload to AWS Lambda.

Comment: Hi tnx, I know that. Problem is that the libraries I want to include have to be installed with conda. I have tried to copy folders of libs from anaconda2/pkgs folder and include them in the zip file but I get: "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named pkg_resources"